# Rust Polars from AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, aws-sdk, python-polars, rust-polars

Polars guide shows example of [loading a file from S3](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/io/aws.html). Unfotunately though, it uses python library `pyarrow` and a function `from_arrow` which also seems to be python specific.

I wonder if it would be possible to **do the same in pure Rust**? Or is my best shot to use Python FFI?

Update: Seems like not possible at the moment, but [work in progress](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4865).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not directly supported, It is achievable by using the aws sdk to read the s3 to an in memory object, then pass that off to the file reader.

```rust
use aws_sdk_s3::Region;

use aws_config::meta::region::RegionProviderChain;
use aws_sdk_s3::Client;
use std::borrow::Cow;

use polars::prelude::*;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let region = "region";
    let bucket = "bucket";
    let key = "key";
    let region = Region::new(Cow::Borrowed(region));

    let region_provider = RegionProviderChain::default_provider().or_else(region);
    let config = aws_config::from_env().region(region_provider).load().await;
    let client = Client::new(&config);

    let req = client.get_object().bucket(bucket).key(key);

    let res = req.clone().send().await.unwrap();
    let bytes = res.body.collect().await.unwrap();
    let bytes = bytes.into_bytes();

    let cursor = std::io::Cursor::new(bytes);

    let df = CsvReader::new(cursor).finish().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", df);
}
```

`Cargo.toml`

```ini
[dependencies]
aws-config = "0.49.0"
aws-sdk-s3 = "0.19.0"
polars = { version = "0.24.3", features = ["lazy", "parquet"] }
tokio = { version = "1.21.2", features = ["full"] }
```